# Bash multiline echo

Tags: linux, bash, echo, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to create a script to list the contents of a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
matched=$(ls -1 /data/ | grep $1)
echo $matched
```

I have added the parameter `-1` to the `ls` command and when executed like this `./script dir` the output is on one row:

```
dir1 dir2
```

I've also tried `echo -e $matched`, but the output was:

```
-e dir1 dir2
```

So how can I list the directories each on separate line ?

Comment: [Never parse the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `ls -1 /data/*$1*` ... unless of course you really mean for `$1` to contain a regular expression, in which case your original script definitely should have had it in double quotes.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, that's useful and I've never thought about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using double quotes around the string to be echoed:

```
echo "$matched"
```

The quotes here cause certain special characters to be preserved; see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes).

**Edit**: See cdarke's comment for a better explanation.

Comment: It worked out, thanks, could you please explain why is like that ?

Comment: Are you using a Mac? If so, the BSD version of `echo` does not have an `-e` option.

Comment: @Teneff http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes ... This use of `ls` is [highly suspicious](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Firstly, never use `echo -e` to begin with. The fact that you see a literal `-e` makes me think You're not using Bash. Forcing this to happen in Bash is unlikely and awkward, requiring something like: `bash --posix -c 'shopt -s xpg_echo; var=foo; echo -e "$var"`

Comment: @WillVousden I'm using Linux Ubuntu which has an `-e` option

Comment: The reason why the quotes are required is that a newline (in this context) is a whitespace character and just a parameter seperator.  Without quotes they are not preserved and `echo` never sees them.

Comment: @WillVousden: The BSD version of `/bin/echo` may not have `-e`, but the Bash builtin `echo` certainly does (`man echo` refers to the external version, not the builtin).

Comment: @Dennis: My bad; I didn't know that. But why, then, does it ignore the `-e` in the original example?

Comment: @WillVousden: Because it's not Bash. Other shells may not support `-e` with their `echo`s (e.g. `dash`).